# I'm changing the value of object property from false to true, yet my v-show condition doesn't reflect that

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Every object in the `reviews` array has a property called `isActive` which is set to false by default. Clicking on the "Show more" `<p>` element toggles isActive for that specific element of the array from false to true and vice-versa but for some reason the elements which are supposed to appear and disappear based on the value of that property are not working as intended.

The console.log(this.reviews) in my function prints the updated array and everything seems to be in order. The elements on which the user has clicked have their `isActive` property changed, however, the v-ifs are not reflecting that.

Am I doing something wrong?

```
<template>
<div v-for='(review, index) in reviews' class="review-container">
    <div class="review-info-container">
        <p>{{ review.text.slice(0,240) }}
            <span class='read-more-dots' v-show='!review.isActive' v-if='review.text.length > 240'>...</span>
            <span v-show='review.isActive' class='extra-text'>{{ review.text.slice(240) }}</span>
        </p>
        <p v-show='!review.isActive' @click='showMoreLess(index)'>Show more</p>
        <p v-show='review.isActive' @click='showMoreLess(index)'>Show less</p>
    </div>
</div>
</template>
```

And my `showMoreLess()` function:

```
showMoreLess(index){
    if (this.reviews[index].isActive) {
        this.reviews[index].isActive = false;
    } else {
        this.reviews[index].isActive = true;
    }
    console.log(this.reviews)
}
```

Comment: You should add `isActive` property to each review before you attach it to `data`.
`reviews.forEach( e => e.isActive = false )` and then `data: { reviews }`.

Comment: Your code seems to work fine in this [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/1ryv5wp8x7?fontsize=14&module=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FReviewList.vue). Can you update it to reproduce the problem?